# How to calculate the radius of convergence of this power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ be a formal pwer series with radius of convergence $R(f)=1$. Set $s_n=a_0+a_1+....a_n$. Let $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_nz^n$. Show that $R(g)=1$.

I noticed that $g(z)-zg(z)=f(z)$, if we are allowed to rearrange the summation of those power series $g(z)$ and $zg(z)$. But we don't know the radius of convergence yet so we can't say so. We can at most say that within $|z|<\min(1,R(g))$, the equation holds. So it means that radius of convergence of $g$ is greater or equal to $1$, but if $|z|>1$, the RHS $f(z)$ diverges, so the radius of convergence can only be $1$?  I forgot to mention that the coefficients and $z$ take on $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to refer to the definition of $R(g)$. Can you prove that if $R(g) < 1$, then the series converges and that if $R(g) > 1$, then the series diverges?

Comment: Yeah...I edited my question, is it right now?

Comment: If you talk about convergence, then your series is not *formal*, so you should probably eliminate this word. You should also specify whether the coefficients are real or complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You want to deduce $(1-z)g(z) = f(z)$, which can be written $$g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} f(z)$$ if $z \not= 1$. Recongnize the first term? The series defining $g$ is just the Cauchy product $$ \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \right) \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \right)$$ and both series in the product have radius of convergence $1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can show a little more: For $r \in [0,1),$

$$\tag 1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(|a_0|+ \cdots |a_n|)r^n < \infty.$$

Proof: Let $h(r) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|r^n.$ Then $h(r)< \infty, r\in [0,1).$ Now fix $r \in [0,1).$ We have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(|a_0|+ \cdots |a_n|)r^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(|a_0|+ \cdots + |a_n|)r^{n/2}\cdot r^{n/2}$$ $$ \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(|a_0|+ |a_1|r^{1/2} + |a_2|(r^{1/2})^2 + \cdots+ |a_n|(r^{1/2})^n)\cdot r^{n/2}$$ $$\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h(r^{1/2})\cdot r^{n/2} = h(r^{1/2})/(1-r^{1/n})<\infty.$$